# How to translate this css code to better lesscss code?

Tags: css, less

Here is my DOM structure:

```
<div class="item">
    <div class="item__icon"></div>
</div>
```

Here is my css code:

```
.item__icon {
    display: none;
}

.item:hover .item__icon {
    display: block
}
```

Then I translate it to lesscss, I use BEM name rule:

```
.item {
    :hover {
        .item__icon {
            display: block;
        }
    }
    &__icon {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

However, I think the `.item__icon` code is duplicated, because when I change the `&__icon`, I have change the `.item__icon` too, this is not good for maintain.

Is there a better to do this ?

Comment: I actually don't see a problem here and would personally even prefer `.item__icon` over `&__icon`. You don't have duplicated code, you just have a duplicated class name.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to actually store the `.item` as a string in a variable, since you are re-using it in the parent level declaration `.item` and its child component `.item__icon`. You can then interpolate it in as such:

```
@item: ~".item";

@{item} {
  &__icon {
    display: none;
  }

  &:hover {
    @{item}__icon {
      display: block;
    }
  }
}
```

This will output:

```
.item__icon {
  display: none;
}
.item:hover .item__icon {
  display: block;
}
```